# Remediation for Implicit PendingIntent Vulnerability

Tags: java, android

I don't know much about Java so I wanted to ask you how I can solve this problem.

When I try to publish my Android application, I get the following error. https://i.ibb.co/KGD2906/Screen-Shot-2022-07-18-at-23-18-11.png

I leave below the solution suggested by Google.
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10437428

I found the problem code

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.UUID;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

public class Scheduler extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private final String EXECUTE_JOB = "org.strongswan.android.Scheduler.EXECUTE_JOB";
    private final Context mContext;
    private final AlarmManager mManager;
    private final PriorityQueue<ScheduledJob> mJobs;

    public Scheduler(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mJobs = new PriorityQueue<>();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(EXECUTE_JOB);
        mContext.registerReceiver(this, filter);
    }

    /**
     * Remove all pending jobs and unregister the receiver.
     * Called via JNI.
     */
    public void Terminate()
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            mJobs.clear();
        }
        mManager.cancel(createIntent());
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(this);
    }

    /**
     * Allocate a job ID. Called via JNI.
     *
     * @return random ID for a new job
     */
    public String allocateId()
    {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    /**
     * Create a pending intent to execute a job.
     *
     * @return pending intent
     */
    private PendingIntent createIntent()
    {
        /* using component/class doesn't work with dynamic broadcast receivers */
        Intent intent = new Intent(EXECUTE_JOB);
        intent.setPackage(mContext.getPackageName());
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Schedule executing a job in the future.
     * Called via JNI from different threads.
     *
     * @param id job ID
     * @param ms delta in milliseconds when the job should be executed
     */
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void scheduleJob(String id, long ms)
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            ScheduledJob job = new ScheduledJob(id, System.currentTimeMillis() + ms);
            mJobs.add(job);

            if (job == mJobs.peek())
            {   /* update the alarm if the job has to be executed before all others */
                PendingIntent pending = createIntent();
                mManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, job.Time, pending);
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        ArrayList<ScheduledJob> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        synchronized (this)
        {
            ScheduledJob job = mJobs.peek();
            while (job != null)
            {
                if (job.Time > now)
                {
                    break;
                }
                jobs.add(mJobs.remove());
                job = mJobs.peek();
            }
            if (job != null)
            {
                PendingIntent pending = createIntent();
                mManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, job.Time, pending);
            }
        }

        for (ScheduledJob job : jobs)
        {
            executeJob(job.Id);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job with the given ID.
     *
     * @param id job ID
     */
    public native void executeJob(String id);

    /**
     * Keep track of scheduled jobs.
     */
    private static class ScheduledJob implements Comparable<ScheduledJob>
    {
        String Id;
        long Time;

        ScheduledJob(String id, long time)
        {
            Id = id;
            Time = time;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(ScheduledJob o)
        {
            return Long.compare(Time, o.Time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest getting help from the code owner/writer themselves since you don't know how this works and you would certainly not want to ruin it, this persion seems to be a ***Tobias Brunner***.

Comment: When I talked to the developer about this problem, he said that this problem can be solved by google, but I don't understand it.

Comment: @MeteOğuzhanBayrampınar The link you posted is exactly what is relevant, and it states several options on how to deal with this issue. They are meant for the developer, and the developer will have to apply the fix. That said, you can of course decide to learn to fix it yourself instead. In that case, could you please make clearer why an answer that simply says what your link says is not enough? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can solve this problem, but I don't have a place to test it because I get this error when I try to upload it to google play console. Since I don't know Java, I wanted to ask someone more knowledgeable about this. @lucidbrot

Comment: did u find any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution will be as follows.

```
    /**
     * Create a pending intent to execute a job.
     *
     * @return pending intent
     */
    private PendingIntent createIntent()
    {
        /* using component/class doesn't work with dynamic broadcast receivers */
        Intent intent = new Intent(EXECUTE_JOB);
        intent.setPackage(mContext.getPackageName());
        int flags = 0;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            flags |= PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE;
        }
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, flags);
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a short description of why this fixes the problem with a link to the documentation, so the solution can be understood easily as opposed to just sharing code without explanation